# filter-branch on current branch and current director only

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I have a local branch with a couple of commits. 
Now I need to rewrite all of those commits and change a file name but only in one specific directory. I don't want any changes to commits not on my local branch.

Running `git filter-branch 'some command' master..HEAD` standing in that directory gives me

```
You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree.
```

Of course I can run this from the top level but that would force me to write my script with the path of the directory I really want to change and eventually I would like to run the same script in a couple of directories without really knowing what there full path is.

Is there a way to run filter-branch and have the script have the current directory as it's working directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not. But just make your script take a parameter and then run this in your toplevel:

```
git filter-branch 'yourscript the/sub/directory' master..HEAD
```